# CV2 resize gives erroneous results randomly when used with nearest neighbor interp

Tags: python, opencv, image-resizing

I use cv2.resize to resize 2d images set in a 3d numpy array of type "uint8" and I want to use nearest neighbor interpolation. I have noticed that it gives (randomly) completely inconsistant result (for example it will output values outside of the range of values of the initial array).

I have tried to reproduce the error with the code below (creating a number of such examples and testing whether there is inconsistant results) and I have noticed that in some runs I have a lot of those and in some others they are just all corrects.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

shape=[512,512,80,10]
nbr_iter=100

for _ in range(nbr_iter):
    img=np.random.randint(0,2,shape,dtype=np.uint8)
    ret=np.reshape(img,(img.shape[0],img.shape[1],-1))
    ret = cv2.resize(ret, (256,256),interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
    ret=np.reshape(ret,(ret.shape[0],ret.shape[1],img.shape[2]))
    if np.max(ret)>1:
        print("inconsistant array (value greater than 1) with value of %s"%(np.max(ret)))
```

In the latest run the code outputs :

```py
inconsistant array (value greater than 1) with value of 130
inconsistant array (value greater than 1) with value of 130
...
```

for all the runs although the values of the initial array lies within [0,1], when looking at the values inside :

```py
ret[ret>1]
[ 16 130  55 130  86  85]
```

I cannot make any sense of the output, why there would have these random numbers so I would be interested to see if others persons can replicate that and where these problems could come from.

Comment: Do not forget to mention answers and comments when editing question bodies.

Answer (score 0):

`np.random.randint()` is right exclusive so your first line is basically `np.zeros(...)`.

UINT8 holds values between 0 and 0xff(255). Why do you think it cannot be larger than 1?

Comment: Corrected the sample code even to do random between 0 and 1. The problem is that I got value in my resized array than are NOT in the original array which is contradictory with nearest neighbor interpolation (on top that the values are way outside the range of initial values of 0's and 1's)

Comment: I could not reproduce your error on [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_lfJRquKbS0fHej7l7va6djKN8qJFA8n)

Comment: I created another [Colab link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1h2zSVIlEGS7lvX4CbdTDqQhMqkjPkRD5). In this one, the image is a float with values ranging [0,1). I used NEAREST_NEIGHBOUR_INTERPOLATION which as you said should not produce anything out of the original range. And, it did not.

Comment: thanks for your answer.
Your code here : 
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_lfJRquKbS0fHej7l7va6djKN8qJFA8n 
pictures exactly the problem I encontered. The ret array before resize is all 0 (because np.randomint between 0 and 1 gives only 0) but after resizing the arrays contains integer up to 255 which does not make any sense (a resized of array of all zeros should be all zeros)
I agree that you other example (with float images) shows the function working as exepected and not producing values out side of the initial range

Comment: I reset the problematic environment and the problem goes away. But, the problem is as you mentioned, this is not some randomized code. It should always perform deterministically. I am exploring through resize source from OpenCV. Will give you a thumbs up if anything comes up.

Comment: That is also what I experienced : it can either work as expected or not at all and restarting the kernel might fix temporarily the issue